# How can Next lock screen (Microsoft) bypass the system lock screen with fingerprint?

Tags: android, fingerprint, lockscreen

I'm currently developing a lock screen application. I have used Next lock screen and realised that it can bypass the system lock screen if fingerprint is enabled. I have done several reseach to find out the way. Unfortunately, I could not do that. But I have some conclusions based on my research:

1. Next lock screen can ONLY bypass the system lock screen if at least 1 fingerprint is set.
2. Next lock screen can ONLY bypass the system lock screen PROPERLY on android 7.1.1 and below. It CANNOT do that on android 8.0. If you have a chance, please use it and you can understand what I am trying to say here.
3. There are differences between android 7.0 and 8.0.

   - On Android 7.0, when an activity shows up ON TOP OF the system lock screen, the keyguard behind stops reading fingerprint. Somehow, Next lock screen enables the keyguard to continue reading the fingerprint but I don't know. I'm trying to do this.
   - On Android 8.0, with the same case, the keyguard behind CAN STILL READ the fingerprint. Therefore, if the fingerprint is correct, the phone is unlocked and I can catch the event of "USER_PRESENT" to dismiss my lock screen. However, Next lock screen fails to function properly.

And now, my question is how I can make the keyguard to continue reading the fingerprint while my custom lock activity is showing on top?

This is what I want: My custom lock screen will show up on top of the system lock screen. The system lock screen can have any type of security methods (password or pattern). If and only if the user enables fingerprint unlock in the system, they can use fingerprint on my custom lock screen to unlock the device (the system lock screen is unlocked at the same time my lock screen disappears)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

They do not run Activity as their lockscreen but they just draw their view into WindowManager and somehow listens for lockscreen unlock and then they hides their UI. Check this - [Android Lockscreen with FingerPrint support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155059/android-lockscreen-with-fingerprint-support)